# Binding to checkbox and getting the selected value using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I need help to create checkbox list using knockout js for a collection Array. I have created the arrayobject , but not sure how to bind it to checkbox and get the corresponding checkbox selected value on click of the checkbox.Below is the js code

```
function axViewModel()
{
 var self = this;
 self.Methods = ko.observableArray([]);

 function addMethod(id, name){
 return {
  Id : ko.observable(id),
  Name : ko.observable(name)
   }
}

 function LoadMethod()
  {
   self.Methods.push(new addMethod('1', 'StartWith');
   self.Methods.push(new addMethod('2', 'Contains');
   self.Methods.push(new addMethod('3', 'Contains');
}

LoadMethod();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: Methods"> <div class="radio"> <label> <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-bind="value: MethodId,checked: $parent.selected"><span data-bind=" text: MethodName" ></span> </label> </div> </div>

self.selected = ko.observable('');
self.Methods = ko.observableArray([{MethodId:2,MethodName:'Athul'},{MethodId:1,MethodName:'Athul'}]);
    self.selected(2);
```

self.selected.subscribe(function(newValue) { alert("new value is " + newValue); });

Comment: Here is the updated code.
 <div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: Methods">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-bind="value: MethodId, checked: $parent.selected, event: { change: $parent.radioMethodSetup(MethodId) }"><span data-bind="    text: MethodName" ></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
self.radioMethodSetup = function (id) {        
      alert(id());                
    }

Problem is this method called everytime.

Comment: dont use change, use click instead or use subscribe function

Comment: the subscribe function will be like this.selected.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("new value is " + newValue);
    });
and remove the event: { change: $parent.radioMethodSetup(MethodId)

all your logics should go inside  the subscribe function

Answer (score 0):

Each of your `method` objects needs another observable that can be tied to the [checked](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) binding. The observable should be a boolean. You could then subscribe to changes on those observables to get the new value on change.

Comment: Below is the code for displaying in the Page, Problem is i get the event is called multiple time and i want the first checkbox to be default selected...
<div class="col-sm-6" data-bind="foreach: Methods">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="optradio" data-bind="value: MethodId, event: { change: $root.radioMethodSetup(MethodId) }"><span data-bind="    text: MethodName" ></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: self.radioMethodSetup = function (id) {
        
    }